# How to determine if specific date is daylight savings time or not?

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am dealing with a badly-programmed 3rd party API that is forcing me to massage some date/time data in objective C.

Instead of returning dates as absolute UNIX time stamps in UTC, it returns dates as formatted strings with no time zone information. (It actually turns out, after talking to one of their developers, that they are actually storing the date/time in their database *as a string without time zone information, not as a timestamp!*) The servers are somewhere in the middle of the US so it's currently on CDT, so theoretically I could just add 'CDT' to the formatted dates and use an NSDateFormatter (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz`) to construct an NSDate. However, depending on the time of year when the date in question comes from, it could be in CST or CDT.

How can I determine whether daylight savings time was in effect at that particular date, so that I can append the proper time zone and calculate the correct UTC date?

Answer (score 8):

Well, I don't think there *is* a correct way to do this.  There are APIs for this such as:

`[NSTimeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:]` and `[NSTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:]`

**BUT** In the transition from CDT to CST, one hour will be repeated so there is no way of knowing whether it is CDT or CST.  Other than that one hour assuming CST and checking for daylight savings time should work.  My suggestion is to set whoever wrote this API on fire.

Comment: Right-- the best option is to change the API. Unfortunately I don't have the power to do that. Is there a way to get an NSTimeZone from an NSDate? That way I can use the isDaylightSavingsTimeForDate: method.

Comment: @Jason Be very careful.  NSDate has nothing to do with NSTimeZone (do unix stamps have a time zone?  No, and it is for the same reason).  The time zone goes on a date *formatter* not the date itself.  So, as I state above, just assume CST (create a timezone with that abbrevation), set that timezone on the formatter, and create an `NSDate` object with the formatter.  It will work except for the repeated one hour.  If daylight savings time is in effect, then adjust the NSDate appropriately.

Comment: I agree about the one-hour repeated during the DST fall-back transition.  Without some other info from the API, you can only guess which of the two it might be, and you might be wrong.

Comment: I want to find that guy as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have a solution:

```
    NSString *originalDateString = <ORIGINAL DATE FROM API>;

    NSDateFormatter *dateStringFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz";

    NSString *tempDateString = [originalDateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" CST"];

    // create a temporary NSDate object
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateStringFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];

    // get the time zone for this NSDate (it may be incorrect but it is an NSTimeZone object)
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                    components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:tempDate];
    NSTimeZone *tempTimeZone = [components timeZone];

    // Find out if the time zone of the temporary date
    // (in CST or CDT depending on the local time zone of the iOS device)
    // **would** use daylight savings time for the date in question, and
    // select the proper time zone
    NSString *timeZone;
    if ([tempTimeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:tempDate]) {
        timeZone = @"CDT";
    } else {
        timeZone = @"CST";
    }

    NSString *finalDateString = [originalDateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", timeZone];
```

Comment: Be careful with time zone abbreviations.  I'm not quite sure how iOS handles it, but there are many zones with the same abbreviations.  You can see a list [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).  For example, CST might mean "China Standard Time"...

Comment: I wonder if you can just pass the zone id `America/Chicago` instead?  If so, you probably won't have to check `isDaylightSavingsTimeForDate` yourself.  It will probably do it internally.  (I am just guessing - I'm not an iOS/ObjectiveC developer)

Comment: @MattJohnson That wouldn't make sense for this API, since "America/Chicago" would be dependent on the date, while a time zone is not.  Also, a quicker way for this API is instead of making another formatters, just add `daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:` to the date you create in `tempDate`.  It will be zero if daylight savings time is not in effect.

Comment: @MattJohnson Unfortunately iOS does not determine daylight savings time automatically from the date formatter. If I put CST when it's supposed to be CDT, it's off by an hour.

Comment: @Jason He meant literally passing "America/Chicago" instead of "CST" to have the system determine the actual time zone :).  Also, you might consider constructing the time zone by name instead of abbreviation to avoid the problem he mentioned above.